# How to change titanium alloy action bar background color

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy

I am new in titanium development. How i can create a custom alloy theme or change the holo theme action bar background. please help me with a example if you have solution.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide the code you have so far. Know that this is not the place to get teh codez.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is with this "actionbar generator". its works amazing to me.
[ActionBar Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=example&compat=holo&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&texture=0&hairline=0&neutralPressed=1&backColor=E4E4E4%2C100&secondaryColor=D6D6D6%2C100&tabColor=33B5E5%2C100&tertiaryColor=F2F2F2%2C100&accentColor=33B5E5%2C100&cabBackColor=FFFFFF%2C100&cabHighlightColor=33B5E5%2C100)

Comment: The actionbar generator is depreciated. Starting with Release 4.0.0, the Titanium SDK exposes the Material Theme color palette attributes

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [this thread](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/146236/actionbar-color) in the Appcelerator forum. In short: You create a style where you define your color and apply it to your actionbar.

Answer (score 0):

[Android Themes documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Android_Themes)

Example:

platform/android/res/values/builtin_themes.xml

```
 <!-- Works for Titanium SDK 3.2.x and earlier when built against Android 4.0x/API Level 14 -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Available for Android 4.0.x/API Level 14 and later -->
    <style name="LightDarkBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"/> 
    <!-- Available for Android 3.0.x/API Level 11 and later -->
    <style name="Light" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"/>
    <style name="Dark" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo"/>
    <!-- Available for all Android versions -->
    <style name="OldLight" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light"/>
    <style name="OldDark" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black"/>
</resources>
```

modify the Android section of your tiapp.xml

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <manifest>
        <application android:theme="@style/LightDarkBar"/>
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
    </manifest>
</android>
```